# How to rebuild an AnimatedWidget in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I'm new in Flutter.

I have an AnimatedWidget which basically toggles an input textfield from a hidden area of the screen onto the visible part, however I need to reload view in some cases.

As far as I know the AnimatedWidget is somehow extended the StatefulWidget, however there is no way to call setState.

Thanks

Comment: If you provide a image of what you want, the better solution can be provided. Because you question is not enough to understand your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class MyState extends State<MyPage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {    
  AnimationController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    controller = AnimationController(duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500), vsync: this);
    loadDbData();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final colorTween =
      ColorTween(begin: Theme.of(context).primaryColor, end: Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark)
        .animate(controller);
    return AnimatedBuilder(
        animation: colorTween,
        builder: (buildContext, child) {
          return Container(
              color: colorTween.value,
          );
        });
  }
```

And for starting animation you can use:

```
controller.forward();
controller.forward(from: 0.5);
controller.reverse();
```

Or you can set listener like this:

```
colorTween.addStatusListener((status) {
    if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
      controller.reverse();
    } else if (status == AnimationStatus.dismissed) {
      controller.forward();
    }
  });
```

Hope it's what you need

Comment: How is `builder()` called? What does `AnimatedBuilder` look like?

Comment: `builder()` is required parameter for `AnimatedBuilder`. And `AnimatedBuilder` doesn't look like anything, it just returns widget from `builder()`, in this example - `Container`

Comment: Thanks. I assumed `AnimatedBuilder` was a class you had to write, but I found out it's a standard Flutter class.